How to change the color of the button when pressed and released?
I'm a novice at Swift. I want to create a button that changes color when pressed by the user. However, it ought to revert back to the original color when the user removes the finger from the button.

I tried different methods shown in tutorials but to no avail.

I’m voting to close this question because it contains code as an image.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask <- This is useful. Welcome to SO!


I want to create a button that changes color when pressed by the user. However, it ought to revert back to the original color when the user removes the finger from the button.

The modern approach to doing this is to supply a background color transformer function. Since your code already has a reference to the button (firstTimeBtn) and an implementation of viewDidLoad, a simple approach is to modify your code as follows:
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    firstTimeBtn.configuration = .filled()
    firstTimeBtn.configuration?.background.backgroundColorTransformer = .init { 
        [weak firstTimeBtn] in
        guard let firstTimeBtn else { return $0 }
        return firstTimeBtn.state == .highlighted ? .green : .red
    }
}

That gives you a button that's red normally but is green while the user's finger is tapping the button. Just change the colors to suit your desires. To set the button's title in the same code, set its configuration?.title.

Note, please, that this has nothing to do with being "a novice at Swift". This is not a language problem; it's about the framework (UIKit). A SwiftUI solution would be totally different, but the language would still be Swift.

Thankyou works like a charm. Now I just need to understand the various elements within the code.

Please don't post "thank you" comments. If the answer solves your problem, you can accept the answer by clicking on the large checkmark at the left of the answer. That completes the question/answer cycle. — Please note that this is not a "charm". It's all standard Swift, operating on documented UIKit button properties.

import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
private let button: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("First Time", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return button
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonPressed(_:)), for: .touchDown)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonReleased(_:)), for: [.touchUpInside, .touchUpOutside])
    view.addSubview(button)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let buttonWidth: CGFloat = 200
    let buttonHeight: CGFloat = 50
    button.frame = CGRect(x: (view.bounds.width - buttonWidth) / 2,
                          y: (view.bounds.height - buttonHeight) / 2,
                          width: buttonWidth,
                          height: buttonHeight)
}

@objc func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
     sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
 }
@objc func buttonReleased(_ sender: UIButton) {
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
}

}

Please do not post code-only answers. A good answer explains what was wrong in the question and it explains how the answer solves the issue.

This is also a very outdated solution. iOS 15+ should be using UIButton.Configuration based solutions.

@HangarRash can you plz give an example of such solution. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

@humble See the other answer by matt.
